# Removing elements with color animation is not working if I use $(this).parent() but works if I use it as a variable - jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here I am doing some animation while removing li elements with some background color change and then sliding up. When I used `$(this).parent()` in my code then it doesn't work, but when I use `$(this).parent()` as a variable then it works. I dont understand why it is happening. Here is my entire code. You may need to include jquery libraries to run this code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <ul class="update">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.<a href="#" id="1" class="delete_button">X</a></li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.<a href="#" id="2" class="delete_button">X</a></li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.<a href="#" id="3" class="delete_button">X</a></li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.<a href="#" id="4" class="delete_button">X</a></li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.<a href="#" id="5" class="delete_button">X</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS -**

```
<style type="text/css">
#main
{
    width:500px;
    margin:50px auto;
}

.update
{
    list-style-type:none;
}

.update li
{
    border-bottom:#dedede dashed 1px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}

.delete_button
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#d02b55;
    margin-left:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:right;
}

.delete_button:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#d02b55;
}
</style>
```

**JavaScript -**

(doesn't work)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete_button").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var dataString = 'id='+id ;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            // url: "ajax/delete-comment.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $(this).parent().animate({
                'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'}, 300).animate({
                opacity: 0.5 }, "slow");
            }, 
            success: function(){
                $(this).parent().slideUp('slow', function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                    });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

(it works)

```
var parent = $(this).parent();
beforeSend: function(){
                parent.animate({
                'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'}, 300).animate({
                opacity: 0.5 }, "slow");
            }, 
            success: function(){
                parent.slideUp('slow', function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                    });
            }
```

Why using variable works and otherwise not?

I put demo at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/php123/HTXv8/2/) but my correct code which is working on my local does not seem to be working at there. Can you please tell me why it is not working on JSFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you call this.parent... 'this' is not refering to your button. That is why if you assign the this.parent to you variable outside the callback works properly.

You can set the context for your Ajax query to the button that is calling it adding the 'context' property to you Ajax call and set it up as this, like so:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        // url: "ajax/delete-comment.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        context: this,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $(this).parent().animate({
            'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'}, 300).animate({
            opacity: 0.5 }, "slow");
        }, 
        success: function(){
            $(this).parent().slideUp('slow', function(){
                $(this).remove();
                });
        }
    });
```

Tthis way your 'this' in the callbacks are referring to your button. Hope is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is inside jQuery AJAX callbacks, `this` refers to the [jQuery XHR Object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) and not an element.